# Apply double non-negative constrain on Sparse PCA

Tags: r, sparse

In Non-negative Sparse PCA, we apply a non-negative constrain in the coordinate matrix. Here I'm up to apply non-negative constrains on both the basis matrix and the coordinate matrix. I'm wondering if there's any research on this.

By the way, I'm using nsprcomp package in R and can I apply this extra constrain using this package?

Answer (score 1):

`nsprcomp` (as of version 0.4.1) only supports enforcing constraints on the loadings.

If you are interested in an approximate matrix factorization $\mathbf{X}\approx\mathbf{P}\mathbf{Q}$ where both $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ only contain non-negative elements, I suggest that you study the non-negative matrix factorization (NMF) literature. For example the [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs.LG/0408058) by Hoyer (2004) is well written.